# Cómo exportar un resultado de un SELECT a un archivo CSV

Tags: java, postgresql, csv

Tengo un código en JAVA para realizar una consulta:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiClase 
{      
    private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://MiServer:5432/MiBD";
    private final String user = "******";
    private final String password = "******";

    public Connection connect() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = null;

        try 
        {
            int FechaInicial;
            int FechaFinal;

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Digite la fecha de inicio del reporte --Desde que fecha se empiezan a tomar los datos--: ");
            FechaInicial = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite la fecha final del reporte --Hasta que fecha se toma los datos--: ");
            FechaFinal = teclado.nextInt();

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MovementsReport3('ID_CUENTA', 'ID_COMERCIO', to_date('"+FechaInicial+"', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('"+FechaFinal+"', 'YYYYMMDD'))");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(2));
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de que los resultados de la consulta sean exportados a un archivo CSV pero no encuentro el código para hacerlo. ¿Hay alguna forma de lograr exportar los resultados a un CSV?

La BD es PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

El JDBC de Postgresql tiene una clase interesante para copiar cualquier consulta en  un archivo externo, se llama [**CopyManager**](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html).

Su método [**`copyOut`**](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html#copyOut-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-) pasa los resultados de una consulta de la base de datos a un flujo de salida (OutputStream) mediante `COPY TO STDOUT`.

Un aspecto interesante es que, desde Java, no es necesario consultar, obtener el recordset, leerlo y escribirlo luego en un flujo de salida. Si no que `CopyManager` te permite ejecutar un comando de copiado a un archivo como si estuvieras directamente en PostgreSQL, pero desde Java. La diferencia de rendimiento es considerable, sobre todo si tenemos que generar un archivo con millones de registros :) .

El método **`copyOut`** está definido así:

```
public long copyOut(String sql,
                    OutputStream to)
             throws SQLException,
                    IOException
Parámetros:
sql - COPY TO STDOUT statement
to - el archivo donde se escribirán los resultados (fila por fila)

Retorna:
número de filas actualizadas para pgsql 8.2+; -1 para versiones anteriores

Throws:
SQLException - on database usage errors
IOException - upon output stream or database connection failure
```

---

#### Un ejemplo de uso sería:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
CopyManager cm = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) con);

//Ruta y nombre del archivo
File file = new File("/documentos/sql.csv");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

String sql="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...";

//Ejecuta el comando COPY indicando el separador `;`


     cm.copyOut("COPY (" + sql 
            + ") TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ';'", fos);
```

---

- [Ver aquí más ejemplos y usos de **`CopyManager`**](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager)
- [Comando `COPY` en la documentación de Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta; 

Me aparece el siguiente error: Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "TO"

En el codigo estoy pidiendo datos para diligenciar la consulta:
      
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM MovementsReport3('529537', '527726', to_date('"+FechaInicial+"', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('"+FechaFinal+"', 'YYYYMMDD')";
        cm.copyOut("COPY ("+sql+")  TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV)", fos);

Puede ser por el tipo de caracter?

Comment: @CristianCamilo Como estaba antes funciona directamente en PGAdmin, pero desde Java no, el motivo lo ignoro. No obstante, de esta manera lo he probado desde Java y me funciona perfectamente: **`cm.copyOut("COPY (" + sql + ") TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ';'", fos);`** Verifica que no haya comillas de más o de menos cuando construyas tu consulta y que el driver JDBC esté actualizado. He actualizado la respuesta con la cadena construida de este modo. Saludos.